# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'where clause' \lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): on clicking search in custom grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a **Custom Grid** using a module in my magento.

When I select  option under *select all* as yes or no and click on *search* (similar to product grid).I get following error.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in
'where clause'"; \lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

I am showing this with screenshot attached?

[image: Screenshot]

*Grid.php*

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
      $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/look')->getCollection();
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }
```

Where should I do to fix this in Grid.php ?

Comment: This ought to be a problem with the prepare collection section of your Grid.php. The problem is that you are referencing a grid column entity_id to a database table which does not have such a column. Without knowing more about your Grid.php it'll be hard to be more precise though.

Comment: @user3154108 Please see the updated question fro code